# Cannot deserialize to string

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, serialization

I'm writing a method to deserialize from .xml file to object. I've got the inner exception that invalid string format to parse from string to Datetime at (7,6) in the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Table>1</Table>
<OrderInfo>
   <OrderID>0</OrderID>
   <OrderType>AtStore</OrderType>
   <Time>22/12/2014 21:07:44</Time>
   <RentStatus>Finish</RentStatus>
   <CancelReason>-</CancelReason>
   <Cashier>test14</Cashier>
   <Session>1</Session>
</OrderInfo>
<CustomerInfo />
<OrderPayment>
   <PaymentType>Cash</PaymentType>
   <Total>258</Total>
   <DiscountPercent>0</DiscountPercent>
   <Discount>0</Discount>
   <Payment>258</Payment>
   <PaymentFromCash>258</PaymentFromCash>
   <PaymentFromWallet>0</PaymentFromWallet>
   <Receive>258</Receive>
   <Exchange>0</Exchange>
</OrderPayment>
<OrderDetails>
   <OrderDetail>
      <ProductID>107</ProductID>
      <Code>5</Code>
      <ProductName>abc</ProductName>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Price>258</Price>
      <DiscountPercent>0</DiscountPercent>
      <Discount>0</Discount>
      <Total>258</Total>
      <Payment>258</Payment>
      <Note />
   </OrderDetail>
</OrderDetails>
```

However, there's no Datetime field in my class:

```
public class Order
{
    public OrderInfo OrderInfo { get; set; }
    public OrderPayment OrderPayment { get; set; }
    public CustomerInfo CustomerInfo { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
public class OrderInfo
{
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public string OrderOnlineID { get; set; }
    public int OrderType { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public int RentStatus { get; set; }
    public string Cashier { get; set; }
    public string Session { get; set; }
    public string CancelReason { get; set; }
}
public class OrderPayment
{
    public int PaymentType { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int DiscountPercent { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public int Payment { get; set; }
    public int PaymentFromCash { get; set; }
    public int PaymentFromWallet { get; set; }
    public int Receive { get; set; }
    public int Exchange { get; set; }
}
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int DiscountPercent { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public int Payment { get; set; }

    public OrderDetail()
    {
        DiscountPercent = 0;
        Total = 0;
        Discount = 0;
        Payment = 0;
    }
}
public class CustomerInfo
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my code for deserializing:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));
Order order;
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
      order = (Order)serializer.Deserialize(reader); //the exception appears here
}
```

When serializing, I also use a string, not a Datetime. So I think that this is just serializing string to xml and deserializing from xml to string. I can't understand why the exception occurs...

Comment: What's your `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` value?

Comment: Invalid string format to parse from string to Datetime at (7,6) in the xml file. Where is this DateTime

Comment: if you get error `exception that invalid string format to parse from string to Datetime` I am `110%`  Sure that you used Datetime data type ..field somewhere

Comment: When serializing, I also use a string, not a Datetime. So I think that this is just serializing string to xml and deserializing from xml to string. I just don't know why that Datetime exception appears.

Comment: If you have an error on the DateTime format, you have to parse the value, for example : string s = "22/12/2014 21:07:44";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: I got the exception at serializer.Deserialize(reader) so there's no chance to use the Parse method.

Comment: @TruxLeo I think what Christopher wants to say is: try parsing that value in a different project and if it gives you exception then the format of your date is wrong.

Comment: Parsing from that string "22/12/2014 21:07:44" to datetime doesn't give any exception. I've edited my post for the full class and xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested you XML document and it has several problems:

The following elements contain string data, but class properties are declared as numeric types:

```
<OrderType>AtStore</OrderType>
...
<RentStatus>Finish</RentStatus>
...
<PaymentType>Cash</PaymentType>
```

I'm guessing these should be enums?

Also, the `Order` element is not closed, but I suspect that is just an issue with copy-pasting the XML into the question.

After fixing these things, it deserialized fine.

Comment: Thanks, my code works well. Howerver, I'm a little confused why it throws datetime format exception.

Comment: That's strange, it didn't throw that in my case. I'm not really sure why that would happen.